# How Do I Make My Header Act In The Same Way As The Parallax Scrolling

Tags: html, css, position, parallax

I have created a parallax scrolling affect on my website, and that all works fine, but the header, even though it is in the same div as that of the parallax scrolling., doesn't stay in the same place, but moves up with the main text. I have tried a lot of thing but none of them seem to work. I have included the HTML and CSS that is relevant. Thanks

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="parallax-effect">
    <h1 class="para"><strong>We Will Beat Coronavirus</strong></h1>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.parallax-effect {
    background-image: url("https://eyeq.photos/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pexels-photo-371633.jpg");
    min-height: 600px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.para {
    size: 100%
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you need any extra CSS that I missed out then just say. Could this please be a CSS fix, not anything to do with JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're absolutely positioning the header against the initial containing block. It is just placed in that spot you specify with top and left and moves up with the rest of the text as the user scrolls down.

What you're looking for is `position: fixed;` which will make it relative to the viewport. You also need to set `position: relative; z-index: -1;` on the .parallax-effect div in order to hide the heading when it crosses the bottom edge of the picture.

```
.parallax-effect {
    background-image: url("https://eyeq.photos/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/pexels-photo-371633.jpg");
    min-height: 600px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.para {
    size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/OJyybGM